# Rails 5.1.5: TypeError: can't cast ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Array::Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm getting a database `ROLLBACK` with this error in development when I try to update a `Puzzle` object's `User` object through the Rails console:

`TypeError: can't cast ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Array::Data`

This only happens when I attempt to use `update` (or `save` after something like `puzzle.user = some_user`). Adding the initial owner commits to the database without issue.

Here are the models in the schema:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "username"
  t.string "password_digest"
  t.string "email"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "location_id"
end

create_table "puzzles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "pieces"
  t.integer "missing_pieces"
  t.string "previous_owners", array: true
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

And here are the `puzzle.rb` and `user.rb` files so far:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :username, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true#, uniqueness: true
    # use bcrypt for password security
    has_secure_password

    has_many :puzzles
    has_many :reviews
    belongs_to :location
end

class Puzzle < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, uniqueness: true
    validates :pieces, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :puzzle_tags
    has_many :tags, through: :puzzle_tags
    has_many :reviews
    delegate :location, to: :user
end
```

Any idea what could be causing the issue?

***Please note: I'm a newbie and using PostgreSQL for the first time. I specifically chose Postgres as my development database instead of SQLite3 because it allows for array data types. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code that attempts to update `previous_owners`?

Comment: How specifically are you trying to update a user in the console?

Comment: Try saving the record without validations e.g. `puzzle.save(:validate => false)`. f it works, then its a validation issue. My guess is that you are assigning the wrong type to a field in the db e.g. assigning a string to an integer

Comment: @moveson I was setting the puzzle's previous_owners to an empty array (i.e., `puzzle.previous_owners = []`) in the console (eventually I'll add the array as a default)

Comment: @muistooshort 
`p = Puzzle.new(name: "Some puzzle", pieces: 1000)`
`u = User.new(username: "user", email: "blah@blah.com", password: "34532h4gktj2hg")`
`p.user = u`
`p.save` (no problem)
`u2 = User.new(username: "user", email: "blah2@blah.com", password: "34532h4gktj2hg")`
`p.update(user_id: u2.id)` (causes rollback & error)

Also tried: `p.user = u2` and then `p.save` and get the rollback with the same error.

Comment: @Darkisa that worked! So it must be a validation issue... Why would it only cause validation issues when I attempt to assign and save a user to a puzzle the second time? Also, please note that assigning the empty array to the puzzle's `previous_owners` property, saving it, and pushing an `owner_id` in there all cause no validation issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `previous_owners` set up as a string array, but you are pushing integers into it. ActiveRecord is good at casting strings to integers and vice versa normally, but as of Rails 5.1.5, that functionality doesn't work in array fields.

Try using a migration to change the field to an integer array. You'll need to do:

```
$ rails g migration change_previous_owners_to_integer_array
```

Then edit the resulting migration file like this:

```
def change
  remove_column :puzzles, :previous_owners, :string, array: true
  add_column :puzzles, :previous_owners, :integer, array: true
end
```